# Can I get $\cos(x)/\!\cos(y)$ if I have $\sin(x)/\!\sin(y)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Can I get $\cos(x)/\!\cos(y)$ if I have $\sin(x)/\!\sin(y)$?

Comment: Simple trigonometric identities give (as long as $y \notin \pi \mathbb{Z}$):

$$ \left\vert \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(y)} \right\vert = \sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin^2(y)} - \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin^{2}(y)} }{ \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin^2(y)} - 1}} $$

So it seems that knowing the value of $\sin(x)/sin(y)$ is not enough as this does not give you $\sin(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume that $\sin(x)=0$ and conclude that nothing cannot be said about $\cos(x)/\cos(y)$

Comment: Well zero is just a special case

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs In this case there is no identity. I am sorry, but your answer is just wrong.